# If $a_n \to z$, then does $\frac{{n \choose 1} a_1 + {n \choose 2} a_2 \dots {n \choose n} a_n}{2^n} \to z$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation-method

It is well known that $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} =2^n$.

**My question:** If $z$ is the limit point of an infinite sequence of real numbers $\{ a_n \}$, then does $$\frac{{n \choose 1} a_1 + {n \choose 2} a_2+ \cdots+ {n \choose n} a_n}{2^n}$$ converge to $z$ as $n\ \to \infty$?

Comment: Note that $\lim {2n \choose n}/2^{2n}=0$, you can probably compose an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Comment: Did you miss the first term $\binom{n}{0}$ on purpose...? (It doesn't really matter since $a_0 / 2^n \to 0$)

Comment: If you start with $0$ rather than $1$, then
$$
\frac{{n \choose 0} a_1 + {n \choose 1} a_2+ \cdots+ {n \choose n} a_{n+1}}{2^n}
$$
is a weighted average of $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1},$ putting most of the weight near $a_{\operatorname{round}((n+1)/2)}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed, that is roughly speaking conditions 2 and 3 of the below theorem. It would be bad if the weight concentrated around specifically the 507th term; then we should see convergence to $a_{507}$. Condition 2 prevents this. Condition 1 is hard to see here becacuse all terms are positive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something far more general is true. Define the doubly half-infinite matrix $ c_{mn}$,
$$ c_{mn} = \frac1{2^m}\binom{m}{n}\mathbb 1_{n\le m} $$
then you're asking if
$$ t_m := \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{mn} a_n  \to z?$$
According to Hardy's Divergent Series, Theorem 2 (page 43) (apparently due to Toeplitz and Schur):

> **Theorem 2.** (Paraphrased) For any such infinite matrix $(c_{mn})_{m,n\ge 0}$, the statement
>   $$\text{“$a_n \to z$ implies $t_m \to z$''}$$
>   is true iff the following conditions for $c_{mn}$ are satisfied:
>
> 1. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_{mn} | < H $ where $H<\infty$ is uniform in $m$,
> 2. for each $n$, $c_{mn} \xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{} 0$,
> 3. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{mn} \xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{} 1$.

For your specific $c_{mn}$, for each of these conditions:

1. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_{mn} | =\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{mn}    = 2^{-m}\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n} = 1$.
2. $c_{mn}  = \frac{m!}{2^m n!(m-n)!} \le \frac{m^n}{n!2^m} \xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{} 0.$
3. see 1.

So the assumptions for Theorem 2 are verified, and the result holds.

(This type of result is a "regularity" result for a summation method, and such methods are the main focus of Hardy's book.)

Comment: +1 for mention of Hardy (my favorite author).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh he writes beautifully!

Comment: Yeah!! Most of my rep here is primarily a result of his *A Course of Pure Mathematics*.

Answer (score 2):

Below is not entirely rigorous.

Since $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, we can pick $N$ such that $a_m$ is close to $z$ for any $m\ge N$.

Let $n$ large, and due to the fact that if $N=O(1)$ (implies $o(n)$),
 sum of $\sum_{k=1}^N {{n}\choose{k}}=O(n^N)$

We have $\frac{{n \choose 1} a_1 + {n \choose 2} a_2+ \cdots+ {n \choose n} a_n}{2^n} $ is close to $\frac{{n \choose 1} (z-\epsilon) + {n \choose 2} (z-\epsilon)+ \cdots+ {n \choose n} (z-\epsilon)}{2^n} $,
close to $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and define $b_n=a_n-z$. Since $a_n\to z$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|b_n|<\epsilon$. Now, consider the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}(b_i+z)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}b_i+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}z=z+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}b_i.$$

We may simplify the problem and only consider the remaining limit. Note that proving the original statement is equivalent to proving

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}b_i=0.$$

For $n\geq N$ split the sum into two parts, $1\leq i<N$ and $i\geq N$. We have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}b_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \binom{n}{i}b_i+\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}b_i\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \binom{n}{i}b_i+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}b_i.$$

Now, the first limit is clearly zero as $\binom{n}{i}=O(n^i)$ which implies the numerator is some polynomial in $n$ while the denominator is an exponential in $n$. Thus, our problem is distilled down to showing

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}b_i=0.$$

To do this, note that

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}b_i\leq \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}|b_i|<\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}\epsilon\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}=\epsilon.$$

Thus,

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=N}^{n} \binom{n}{i}b_i$$

is bounded by every positive number and hence is $0$ in the limit. We conclude

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}a_i=z.$$

Comment: (+1) I was in the process of typing this exact same proof, which I think comes out as essentially the same proof as the general theorem (and of course, looks very similar to the same result for Cesaro sums)